# Drupal: hook_url_inbound_alter in url_rewrite: rewrite query part of URL for paging

Tags: drupal, url-rewriting, drupal-7

I'm trying to use url_rewrite to work around nonfriendly parameters in URL of `paging` module. I wish to turn URLs like `page-title.html?page=0,1` to `page-title/page1.html`.

Here are my hooks:

```
function mymod_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
    $localPath = $path . '?' . $options['query'];
    dpm("_url_outbound_alter($localPath)");
    if (preg_match('|(.+)\.html\?page=0%2C(\d+)|', $localPath, $matches)) {
        $path = "${matches[1]}/page${matches[2]}.html";
        unset($options['query']);
        dpm("altering path to $path");
    }
}

function mymod_url_inbound_alter(&$result, $path, $path_language) {
    if (preg_match('|(.+)/page(\d+)\.html|', $path, $matches)) {
        //$result = "${matches[1]}.html?page=0,${matches[2]}";
        $result = "${matches[1]}.html";
        //$_GET['q'] = "page=0,${matches[2]}";
        $_GET['page'] = "0,${matches[2]}";
        dpm("altering in-path to $result");
    }
}

function mymod_boot() {}
```

Is it impossible to add query part in hook_url_inbound_alter?

- If I comment out
  mymod_url_outbound_alter, it works,
  bot comma us URL-encoded - OK, it did show the friendly URL.
- If I enable both, the
  page goes into infinite redirect 301
  loop.
- The commented out variants also
  don't seem to work.

Yes, I know it's better to fix `paging` to use non-query URL. But the module is a little too complex to do that reliably. `pagination` module lacks features for me.

Is the problem in URL altering? What can I do to make it work?

Comment: I must say I am a bit confused. You tagged this question drupal-6, yet hook_url_outbound_alter (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7) has only been around since Drupal 7. On the other hand, the paging module (http://drupal.org/project/paging) has not yet been ported to Drupal 7 and is only available for Drupal 6 and earlier.

Comment: I use url_alter module, in order to have forward compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$options['query']` is an array that contains the query parameters and their values, so you would have to do something like

```
$localPath = $path . '?' . $options['query']['page']
```

Also note that `$path` has not been rewritten by the Path module yet. Here is what works for me:

```
function pageing_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path)
{
    if ($path == 'admin/content' && isset($options['query']['page']))
    {
        $path = 'admin/content/page' . $options['query']['page'];
        unset($options['query']['page']);
    }
}

function pageing_url_inbound_alter(&$path, $original_path, $path_language)
{
    if (preg_match('|admin/content/page(\d+)|', $path, $matches))
    {
        $path = 'admin/content';
        $_GET['page'] = $matches[1];
    }
}
```

This is for Drupal 7 RC3